# Reading Avro File in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have read an avro file into spark RDD and need to conver that into a sql dataframe. how do I do that.

This is what I did so far.

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.mapred.{AvroInputFormat, AvroWrapper}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable

val path = "hdfs://dds-nameservice/user/ghagh/"
val avroRDD = sc.hadoopFile[AvroWrapper[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord]](path)
```

When I do:

```
avro.take(1)
```

I get back

```
res1: Array[(org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper[org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord], org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable)] = Array(({"column1": "value1", "column2": "value2", "column3": value3,...
```

How do I convert this to a SparkSQL dataframe?

I am using Spark 1.6

Can anyone tell me if there is an easy solution around this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For `DataFrame` I'd go with Avro [data source directly](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro):

- Include spark-avro in packages list. For the latest version use:

  ```
  com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0
  ```
- Load the file:

  ```
  val df = spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
    .load(path)
  ```

Comment: `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4` works too where as `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.4` doesn't. Details are in the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27623)

Answer (score 0):

If your project is maven then add below latest dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After that you can read `avro` file like below

```
val df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").option("header","true").load("C:\\Users\\alice\\inputs\\sample_data.avro")
```